# Триггер таблицы - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, триггер

Есть таблицы "Клиент" и "Заказ".
Клиент имеет поля "ID"(pk), "ФИО" и "Постоянство"(bool). 
Заказ имеет поля "Идентификатор"(pk), "Идентификатор_Клиент"(fk), "Дата приёма", "Дата получения".

Клиент становится постоянным, когда количество его заказов превышает 3.

Хочу сделать триггер - чтобы при каждой вставке/удалении строки в Заказах высчитывалось количество Заказов на каждого человека, выполнялось условие, строка вставлялась, а поле "Постоянство" принимало корректное значение.

Что сделал:

```
DECLARE s int;
BEGIN
    SELECT count("Заказ"."Идентификатор")
    INTO s
    FROM "Заказ" inner join "Клиент"  on "Клиент"."Идентификатор" = "Заказ"."Идентификатор_Клиент"
    WHERE ("Заказ"."Идентификатор_Клиент" = new."Идентификатор_Клиент");

    UPDATE "Клиент"
        SET "Постоянный" = CASE when s >= 3 then TRUE else FALSE END
        WHERE "Клиент"."Идентификатор" = new."Идентификатор_Клиент";
        return new;
END;
```

И создаю триггер BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE ON "Заказ" FOR EACH ROW.

Но в таком случае: 
а) После успешной вставки третьей строки в "Заказ" Клиент постоянным не становится, становится только после создания четвёртой строки.
б) Строка из "заказ" при удалении не удаляется

Куда вклинить удаление строки в данную функцию? Или как его грамотно составить? Заранее спасибо

Comment: *создаю триггер BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE* Допустим, клиент делает третий заказ, выполняется триггер, он помечается постоянным, затем собственно вставка даёт ошибку... Действия по изменению выполняют только после успешного изменения - т.е. в AFTER UPDATE/DELETE.

Comment: Дельный комментарий. Это я уже поменял. Суть вопроса не поменялась, в этом я не преуспел. Ещё что подскажете?

Comment: А по сути - если некие данные (наличие статуса Постоянный покупатель) могут быть получены из иных данных, они вообще не должны храниться в таблице. Их следует получать запросом в тот момент, когда они потребуются.

Comment: Хмм, согласен. Но это является лабораторной по БД, так что наверное такая оплошность не сильно повлияет. Тем более, 4 предыдущих лаб связанных с этой БД преподаватель принял. Не будет здорово менять базу после выполнения уже такого кол-ва заданий

Comment: Вы в качестве первого задания СОЗДАВАЛИ эту структуру?

Comment: Была дана тема, по теме я создавал структуру

Comment: Ну тады и фиг с ею.

Answer (score 0):

Схематично:

```
/* AFTER INSERT OR DELETE ON Заказ */
BEGIN
    UPDATE "Клиент"
    SET "Постоянный" = ( SELECT COUNT(*) > 3 
                         FROM "Заказ"
                         WHERE "Идентификатор" = NEW."Идентификатор" )
    WHERE "Идентификатор" = NEW."Идентификатор" ;
END
```

PS. UPDATE не меняет количества записей. Но если в структуре таблицы `Заказ` есть поле типа `Отменён` - то триггер должен работать и на UPDATE, и в него нужно добавить соотв. условие `AND NOT "Отменён"`.